# Relative layout in ListView android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to fetch data from RSS in my android app. I need the data in a specific format. I am able to do everything but get my ListView to look as I want. It currently looks like

[image]

We can see that the eye symbol and the number are not aligned. And that the eye symbol is below the left thumbnail. I want it to look like

[image]

Refer to the 1st list item, left oval. The eye view image and number are aligned with each other and to the bottom of left thumbnail. And at the place of 2nd empty oval I want another TextView where I would show the source of news as text.

My current code for 1 iteam in ListView goes like this :-

```
<!-- postitem.xml -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/postThumb"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postTitleLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/postThumb"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/postThumb"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Place for title"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postDateLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/postThumb"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/postThumb"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="April 12, 2013"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postViews"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/postDateLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eye"
    android:layout_below="@id/postDateLabel"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="1212"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/eye"
    android:layout_width="13dp"
    android:layout_height="7dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/postDateLabel"
    android:layout_below="@id/postDateLabel"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/eye" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would be thankful if someone could share a good resource where I could learn this UI designing easily.

Thanks

Comment: “One should not pursue goals that are easily achieved. One must develop an instinct for what one can just barely achieve through one’s greatest efforts.” ― Albert Einstein

Comment: As much as that is my motto but this one I need a bit urgently. I give all the time in a day that I could :( help is the only word or this one..

Comment: You may have an easier time if you wrap everything but the image in a vertical `LinearLayout`

Comment: I will give it a shot. Thanks. But how do we make these decisions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is basicaly this line:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/postThumb"
```

in your postDateLabel.

You said, okay, align this label to the thumbnail bottom, and when you say that you want the eye and the text below the postDateLabel, that's where it ends up.
You're gonna buy me a beer for this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/postThumb"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_go" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postTitleLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/postThumb"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/postThumb"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Place for title"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postDateLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/postViews"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/postThumb"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="April 12, 2013"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postViews"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/postThumb"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/postDateLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eye"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="1212"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/eye"
    android:layout_width="13dp"
    android:layout_height="7dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/postThumb"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/postDateLabel"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_spinner_ab_pressed_holo_dark" />
```

P.S. You have a lot of unnecessary atributes set in xml.. I just did this in a few sec to help you. You should read how RelativeLayout and LinearLayout work.

Comment: When you find out how layouts work: for example LinearLayout every single element is below the previous one, in relative layout you have to tell the elements where should they be **relatively** from some other elements or their parent.. Etc. When you find out how they work you will get better in making decisions which layout to choose to make things exactly the way you want it. Good luck :)

Comment: I have edited my answer as i copied the same code you have provided. This is the fixed one. Sorry :)

Comment: @divyenduz if it helped, you could consider approving the answer ;)

Comment: Please help me with showing the source as well. Answer accepted.

Comment: @divyenduz, what source?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to align is to use Linear layout and put imageview and textview within that layout

For example :-

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="Horizontal" >

      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              />
```